# Unable to access resources on linux in windows domain

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, networking

I am trying to access MySQL on a linux box from a windows server. I have created a user foo@10.% and commented out the bind-address line in my.cnf and I am still unable to connect.

I have an Ubuntu 13.10 Linux 64-bit box running MySQL. It is on a network with a Windows domain. The linux box isn't joined to the domain, but it is on the network. In other words, it is getting its IP address from the domain controller and is using it for DNS. So that's good.

From the linux box, I can ping Windows servers on the domain by IP address. However, those windows servers cannot ping the linux box. I suspect I need to change network or firewall or port settings on the linux box, but I'm not sure where I need to look. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to open the port 3306...maybe a firewall issue??

Answer (score 0):

disable your linux box sealinux

```
root@XXXXX /]# vim /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
# enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
# permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
# disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
# targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
# mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Alter you file to look like this ! 
I would just open a port for 3306 for the mysql - since disabled will open all port ! be carefull here ! 
Initial test this and if you get you connection to work then apply a port rule on our filewall

Answer (score 0):

Linux box was a vm running under VirtualBox with NAT as network type.
**Change guest network from NAT to Bridged Adapter in VirtualBox.**
That resolved the issue. I am mortified I overlooked this.